# XSL - how to set variable as integer if it comes from string

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

> XPTY0004  :   The operator    '   +   '    is not defined for operands of type
>     xs:string    and    xs:integer

IMPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LeveL Plan="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


<space2000>
<values>
<value jak="77" rak="12"</value>
<value jak="66" rak="345"></value>
<value jak="-50" rak="67"></value>
<value jak="-30" rak="-89">1</value>
</values> 

</space2000>


</LeveL>
```

MY TRY:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:fn ="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="(LeveL/space2000/values)">
<xsl:variable name="JJJ"  select="(format-number(((value/@jak) div 2),'0'))"/>
<xsl:variable name="RRR"  select="format-number(((value/@rak) div 2),'0')"/>
<xsl:text>
O
</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>LA</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$JJJ"></xsl:value-of>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:text>LO</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$RRR"></xsl:value-of>
<xsl:text>
O
</xsl:text>

<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="( $JJJ > '0')">
        <xsl:value-of select="A"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="( $JJJ < '0')">
        <xsl:value-of select="B"/>
     </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="( $RRR > '0')">
        <xsl:value-of select="C"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="( $RRR < '0')">
        <xsl:value-of select="D"/>
     </xsl:when>   
     <xsl:when test="( ( $RRR + '50') < '0' )">
        <xsl:value-of select="X"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="( '-100' < ( $RRR + '1') < '100' )">
        <xsl:value-of select="X"/>
     </xsl:when>


</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so I would like ro recive something like:
A
C
B
D
X

but xsl

dont't like + ( is not trusting its integer :)

don"t like < ( the other way > is for him acceptable :)

> SO MY QUESTION IS
>
> a) How to set variable (or element) as integer able to do mathematics?
>
> b) How to test if variable is bigger than -100 and smaller than 100 ?

PLEASE HEEEEEELP :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a pure XML issue, nothing to do with XSLT: `"<"` must be escaped as `"&lt;"`. (But with XSLT 2.0, it's often more convenient to use the "lt" operator rather than "<").

Second point: don't put your numbers in quotes. Write 50, not '50'.

Third: it's a good idea to declare the types of your variables, that way it's much clearer what's going on. e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="JJJ" select="format-number(...)" as="xs:string"/>
```

Finally, if you want to add a string and a number, convert the string to a number first using `xs:integer()`, `xs:double()`, or the `number()` function.

Comment: Nice explanation for the datatypes sir. plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below scripts, whether helping u.

**XML:**

```
<LeveL Plan="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<space2000>
    <values>
        <value jak="77" rak="12"></value>
        <value jak="66" rak="345"></value>
        <value jak="-50" rak="67"></value>
        <value jak="-30" rak="-89">1</value>
    </values> 
</space2000>
</LeveL>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:fn ="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="(LeveL/space2000/values/value)">
    <xsl:variable name="JJJ"  select="((@jak/number(.)) div 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RRR"  select="((@rak/number(.)) div 2)"/>

    <xsl:text>LA </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$JJJ"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:text> and  LO </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$RRR"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:text> Rank </xsl:text>

<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="( $JJJ > 0)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'A'"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="( $JJJ lt 0)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'B'"/>
     </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="( $RRR > 0)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'C'"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="( $RRR lt 0)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'D'"/>
     </xsl:when>   
     <xsl:when test="( ( $RRR + 50) lt 0 )">
        <xsl:value-of select="'X'"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="(-100 lt ( $RRR + 1) and ( $RRR + 1) lt 100)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'X'"/>
     </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:** (I added some text for display)

```
LA 38.5 and  LO 6 Rank A
LA 33 and  LO 172.5 Rank A
LA -25 and  LO 33.5 Rank B
LA -15 and  LO -44.5 Rank B
```